# multiple Fragments with different expandableList's for same data

Tags: android, list, fragment, expandablelistview

this question might be very noobish but I'm just not able to find a right solution.

**So here is my problem:**

I want do display the data (a `java.util.List` with my `TaskObjects`) in multiple `ExpandableLists` (lets say 5) each in a own Fragment so that the user is able to swipe between the different Lists.
At the moment I have a `MainFragmentActivity` that contains the `java.util.List`, the `PageViewer` and a 'extended' `FragmentPagerAdapter` (like [TabsAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)) that contains the Tabs `AllTaskFragment` and `OverDueTaskFragment`. These two Fragments have each a own `ExpandableList` and `ExpandableListAdapter` (writen by me).

Now when the user clicks on a child in any `ExpandableLists` how do i need to notify the other Fragments `ExpandableListAdapter` to update? I tried to call the `MainFragmentActivity` and from there call all Fragments but then the fragments `ExpandableListAdapters` were 'null', but why?

**update:**

I guess I solved the issue, atm Is working with:

If something changes in any ExpandableListAdapter, I call updateTabs() in

**MainFragmentActivity**

```
    public void updateTabs() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tabsAdapter.getCount() ; i++) {
            UpdateableFragment updateableFragment = (UpdateableFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(mViewPager.getId(),i));
            updateableFragment.updateFragment();
        }
    }

    private String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index){
         return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
    }
```

which simply calls in each fragment the method

```
public void updateFragment() {
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Is this a good approach? Or will this maybe rise some issues?

Comment: please provide a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing for such applications is to keep track of the ArrayAdapters. If you call `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, it will tell its view to update.

Comment: I tried with a interface 'UpdateableFragment' which has a update-Method and put that over the Fragments to call the adapter that I stored in a instance variable, but every time the method has been called, I got a NullPointerException for the adapter...
public void updateFragment() {adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}

Comment: How did you get the `adapter`?

Comment: I store it as a instance of the class.
protected ExpandableListTaskAdapter adapter;

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I call the wrong fragments...I guess(pretty sure)
for(int i = 0 ; i < tabsAdapter.getCount() ; i++) {
   UpdateableFragment updateableFragment = (UpdateableFragment) tabsAdapter.getItem(i);
   updateableFragment.updateFragment();
  }